# Python webscraping with Selenium chrome driver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get the number of publications of an instagram account which is in a span tag by using **Python Selenium** with **Chrome driver** this is a part of the html code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr" class="js logged-in client-root js-focus-visible sDN5V">
<head>-</head>
  <body class style>
    <div id="react-root"> == 50
    <form enctype^murtipart/form-data" method="POST" role="presentation">_</form>    
    <section class=”_9eogI E3X2T">
     <div></div>
     <main class="SCxLW o64aR " role=”main">
      <div class=”v9tJq AAaSh VfzDr">
        <header class=" HVbuG">_</header>
►       <div class="-vDIg">_</div>
►       <div class="_4bSq7">_</div>
▼       <ul class=” _3dEHb">
▼         <li class=” LH36I">
▼           <span class=" _81NM2">
                <span class="g47SY 10XF2">6 588</span>
                "publications"
            </span>
          </li>
```

**THE PYTHON CODE**

```py
def get_publications_number(self, user):
    self.nav_user(user)
    sleep(16)
    publication = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(id,"react-root")]/section/main/div/ul/li[1]/span/span')
```

**THE ERROR MESSAGE**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
 {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(id,"react-root")]/section/main/div/ul/li[1]/span/span"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

**IMPORTANT:**

This xpath is pasted from the Chrome element inspector so I  don't think it's the problem. When I put `self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath()` (with 's') there will be no error and if I do:

`for value in publication:
    print(value.text)`

there will be no error too but nothing will be printed

**SO THE QUESTION IS:**

Why am I getting this error while the Xpath exists?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? How about removing elements from the XPath one by one and checking the result each time? Also, shouldn't `'//div[contains(id,"react-root")]'` just be `'//div[@id="react-root")]'` ?

Comment: I thought about that but this path is given by the element inspector of Chrome so the path is not actually the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
'//div[@id="react-root"]//ul/li//span[contains(., "publications")]/span'
```

**Explanation:**

- `//div[@id="react-root"]` << find the element which has the id of "react-root"
- `//ul/li` << inside the found react root find elements anywhere (`//`) which are `li` elements which are children of an `ul` tagged element
- `//span[contains(., "publications")]` << in the found `li` elements find span elements anywhere which contain `publications` as text
- `/span` get span elements of the found `span`

One more thing: `find_element_by_xpath` returns the first element which matches. In case you have more than one 'publications', you can collect them all with the xpath above (if you want to ) if you just use `find_elements_by_xpath` instead of `find_element_by_xpath` in selenium.

Recently I found [this page](https://librarycarpentry.org/lc-webscraping/02-xpath/index.html) which is a quite good read to start mastering Xpath, check it out if you want to know more.

Comment: doesn't work: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@id="react-root")]//span/span[contains(text(), "publications"] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@id="react-root")]//span/span[contains(text(), "publications"]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: @Seye there was a typo, fixed

Comment: a typo, the xpath is the right one so there is no typo in it

Comment: I have updated my answer, not your question (typo-wise)

Comment: @Seye added my final edit, it looks up the span of yours by finding the text node "publications" then select the child span of the container span.

Comment: not working:

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div[@id="react-root"]//ul/li//span[contains(., "publications")]/span/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)

Comment: Removed the `/text()` part. I've been working lately so much JS that I forgot that selenium needs the element and not the text node.

Comment: this is what it prints <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="cc8bc3f8ba96499640c2d95690a3731a", element="10b07725-8a8c-4f82-bfe6-3ca9c46bdfeb")>

How to make it printing 6588 THE NUMBER OF PUBLICATIONS?

Comment: thank you  it worked, I hope that you will explain me why

Comment: @Seye I've added the explanation, I hope you'll like it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```py
//div[contains(id,"react-root")]/section/main/div/ul/li[1]/span/span
```

Use this Xpath. It might work. I think you made a coma error there.

Comment: i did not forget the coma after "id"

Comment: Did you still try copy pasting it? I had to remove an extra coma that's why I brought it up.

Comment: Try going to the page, Clicking on the element, Click on 'Copy full Xpath' and then paste it.

Comment: that's exactly what I did